# How to stop multipeer connectivity transfer in ios?

Tags: ios, connectivity

i'm using the multipeer connectivity framework to transfer ressource between two phones using the sendResource(at:withName:toPeer) function. My question is, is there a way to stop the transfer from the receiver side ? I want to do this, because if i already have the ressource on the receiver phone, i don't want it again. Is it possible, or do i have to wait for the transfer to finish in order to dismiss it ? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can't you first check if the receiver has the resource? The sender would first ask the receiver if there is need for transfer, and act accordingly.

Comment: Make sense. I'll try to do this . I should have thought of that by myself. Thanks!